# Howdo I display all the images from a field in a view?

Tags: 7, views, media

I'm trying to display multiple images from an image field in one view as an Owl Carousel, but I only see a maximum of 5 images to be displayed there. 
Googleing it, I found that there's an option **ALL,** that should display all of the images, but it just doesn't appear to me, so do you know what do I need to configure to enable ALL the images in that field?

**General setup:** I'm using Drupal 7x, with a sub-theme from Bootstrap and Views 7.x-3.20.

**Views setup:** it was created as an Unformatted list and it's showing just Fields one of them is the image field you can see below.

In the red box I've seen the ALL option, but it just doesn't appear in my setup. 
[image]

Thanks, 
Daniel.

Comment: Please give more info about your exact setup especially your views setup as the 5 image limitations is not part of view or owlcarousel default.

Comment: General setup: I'm using Drupal 7x, with a sub-theme from Bootstrap and Views 7.x-3.20. 
Views setup: it was created as an Unformatted list and it's showing just Fields. 
Any other info needed?

Comment: I was thinking drupal 8, give all the details as part of your quesetion, in the comments they might get overlooked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You see the limited number of values (as a drop-down) in Views instead of a text field where you can type in `all` or some number because you have limited the number of values this field can take in its settings.

Check your Content type field settings for "Imagenes" and see if it's limited:

[image: Five values Field settings]

Since this is in your field settings it's enough to set your Views field multi-settings to `5` because there are never more than five values in this particular case.

Comment: That was exactly what was causing it. Thanks a lot @prkos